# Função POST do pacote httr retorna NA

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

Estou tentando fazer um script no R para fazer um POST no site: http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sinannet/cnv/violebr.def, porém não estou obtendo sucesso. O objetivo é extrair a tabela de dados gerada depois da atualização dos dados. Tudo parece ocorrer bem, mas a função POST (ou mesmo a GET) do pacote httr retorna NA e não uma html, como esperado nesse caso. Segue o código que estou usando:

```
link <- 'http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sinannet/cnv/violebr.def'

dados <- list("Linha" = "Munic%EDpio_de_notifica%E7%E3o",
           "Coluna" = "--N%E3o-Ativa--",
           "Incremento" = "Freq%FC%EAncia",
           "Arquivos" = "violeac15.dbf",
           "pesqmes1" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SM%EAs_1%BA_Sintoma%28s%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "pesqmes2" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SMunic%EDpio_de_notifica%E7%E3o" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SRegi%E3o_de_Sa%FAde_%28CIR%29_de_notif" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SMacrorreg.de_Sa%FAde_de_notific" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SDiv.adm.estadual_de_notific" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SMicrorregi%E3o_IBGE_de_notific" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SReg.Metropolit%2FRIDE_de_notific" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "pesqmes8" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SMunic%EDpio_de_resid%EAncia"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SRegi%E3o_de_Sa%FAde_%28CIR%29_de_resid" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SMacrorreg.de_Sa%FAde_de_resid%EAnc"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SDiv.adm.estadual_de_resid%EAncia" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SMicrorregi%E3o_IBGE_de_resid%EAnc" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SReg.Metropolit%2FRIDE_de_resid" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "pesqmes14" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SUF_Ocorr%EAncia" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SCiclo_de_Vida" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "pesqmes16" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SFaixa_Et%E1ria" = 2,
           "SSexo" = 4,
           "SRa%E7a" = 2,
           "pesqmes19"  = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SEscolaridade" = 2,
           "pesqmes20" = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil",
           "SLocal_ocorr%EAncia" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_repeti%E7%E3o" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SLes%E3o_Autoprov" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_F%EDsica" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Psico%2Fmoral" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Tortura" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Sexual"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "STraf._Seres_Huma"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Finan%2FEcono" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Negli%2FAband"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Trab._Infant"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SViol_Interv_Legal" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SOutra_Violencia" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SFor%E7_corp._espanc" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEnforcamento" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SObj._Contundente" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SObj._perf-cortant" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SSubs_Obj_Quente"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEnvenenamento" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SArma_de_fogo" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SAmea%E7a" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SOutra_Agress%E3o" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SAss%E9dio_Sexual" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEstupro" = 1,
           "SAtent._viol_pudor" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPornog_Infantil" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SExplora%E7%E3o_Sexual" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SOutras_Violencias" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SSusp._uso_alcool" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPai" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SM%E3e" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPadrasto" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SMadrasta" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SConjuge" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEx-Conjuge" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SNamorado%28a%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEx-Namorado%28a%29"  = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SFilha%28a%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SIrm%E3o%28a%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SAmigos%2FConhec" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SDesconhecida%28a%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SCuidador%28a%29" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "Spatrao%2FChefe" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPes_com_Rel_Inst" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPolicial_Ag.Lei" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SPropria_Pessoa" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SOutros_V%EDnc" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEnc._Setor_Saude" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "SEvolu%E7%E3o_do_caso" = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__",
           "zeradas" = "exibirlz",
           "formato" = "table",
           "mostre" = "Mostra")

httr::POST(url = link, body = dados)
```

Ao executar esses comandos, temos:

```
Response [http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sinannet/cnv/violebr.def]
Date: 2017-04-02 03:24
Status: 200
Content-Type: text/html
Size: 1.74 kB
NA
```

Note que, o status é 200 (indicando que tudo ocorreu bem), porém não temos uma html! Alguma ideia para solucionar o problema?

Comment: O lado esquerdo da lista dados não leva aspas, pois você está atribuindo valores. Além disso, você já tentou obter esses dados via pacote datasus: https://github.com/danicat/datasus?

Comment: Conheço o pacote, porém acabei tentando solucionar o problema dessa forma para treinar web scraping. Vou testar as duas sugestões, muito obrigado!

Comment: Oi @José, no momento o pacote só tem disponível dados do Sistema de Informação de Mortalidade. Estou querendo informações referente a casos de estupro no Brasil. Contudo, muito obrigado!

Comment: você sabe qual o nome da base em que constam os casos d estupro?

Comment: No sinan (Sistema de Informação de Agravos de Notificação), @José.

Answer (score 2):

Rumenick, é um problema de encoding. O `httr` tenta transformar o output em UTF-8 e quando faz isso, deixa NA.

A solução é inserir manualmente o encoding, que no caso é `'latin1'`:

```
req <- httr::POST(url = link, body = dados)
html <- httr::content(req, 'text', encoding = 'latin1')
html

[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML ...
```

Não se esqueça de usar pacotes apropriados para ler elementos da página, ao invés de trabalhar com a string. coisas do tipo:

```
library(rvest)
html_read(html) %>%
  html_node('#idDoQueVcPrecisa') %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @JulioTrecenti! Consegui solucionar parte do problema.